# App crashing after strings are displayed in sequence using Threads

Tags: java, android

I want to display some words(Strings) in sequence , each for some  time, I am using this code but after all the words are shown, the app crashes, i want it to return to previous page after all words have been shown, please help, thanks in advance.

```
  final TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textid);
        Thread t=new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run(){

                while(!isInterrupted()){

                        try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);  //1000ms = 1 sec

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                        public void run() {
                            count++;
                            textView.setText(words[count]);

                        }
                    });

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: add the code sample where you started the thread

Comment: Can you post a stack trace? Just a guess, but I am going to assume it crashes because you never kill the while loop and run out of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not checking to see if count is within the bounds of words.

You need to change

```
count++;
textView.setText(words[count]);
```

To

```
count++
if (count < words.length){
    textView.setText(words[count]);
}else{
    // Assuming you are inside an activity called MyActivity
    MyActivity.this.finish();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much and it should be if(count<words.length) instead, works after that.